# While undeleting deleted answer, the snippet seems missing

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Yesterday I made an answer to this question [Why does width and height affect how a flex item is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878379/why-does-width-and-height-affect-how-a-flex-item-is-rendered/44918847#44918847). I got some downvotes and so I decided to check am I missed something. I temporarily deleted it for reviewing and then undeleted it.

#### Then the snippet seems missing.

#### I set the snippet to hidden by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the post is scored -3 or lower, all snippet functionality is completely disabled to prevent abuse cases and it will only ever show the code. Thus, if you have the snippet set to hide the code by default, the entire thing gets hidden because there's nothing left to show.

**Note**: This is not new behaviour. This functionality was added very shortly after Stack Snippets were implemented based on feedback from the original announcement.

Comment: Is this new behavior? If not, is this documented anywhere? First time I hear about it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not new. This functionality was added very shortly after Stack Snippets were implemented based on feedback from the original announcement.

Comment: Ironically enough, [I suggested exactly this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269906/447356) but never got any response that it was done. On the contrary, looked like Marc declined it. So it was done silently?

Comment: OK, found the announcement of the change, made via a [comment by Haney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0/270981#comment92448_270981).

Comment: @ShadowWizard which search tool you are using to find out old posts even comments?

Comment: @ShadowWizard ugh, have an edit

Comment: @SagarV no tool, I searched for a post on MSO (that's where snippets were introduced) and went over the answers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added [tag:status-completed] to your post.